# "undefined reference to `____: :___`" error for pure virtual functions when I seperate my files into cpp and header files

Tags: c++, class, oop, virtual-functions

So I have the Book class that inherits from Publication.

Publication has two pure virtual functions which I implemented in Book.

**The code worked before I tried seperating into header and cpp files**

`classes.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Publication
{
protected:
  // Common attributes
  string title;
  float price;

public:
  // Two pure virtual functions that will need implementation in derived classes
  virtual void getData() = 0;
  virtual void putData() = 0;

};


class Book : public Publication 
{
private:
  int pages;

public:
  void getData();
  void putData();

};
```

`classes.cpp`

```
#include "classes.h"
// getData implementation - gets inputs from user
void Book::getData () {
  cout << "Enter title: ";
  cin >> title;
  cout << "Enter price: ";
  cin >> price;
  cout << "Enter number of pages: ";
  cin >> pages;
  cout << endl;

}

// putData implementation - prints out Book info
void Book::putData() {
  cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
  cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
  cout << "Pages: " << pages << endl;

}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "classes.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
  Book book1;

  book1.getData();

  book1.putData();
  

  return 0;
}
```

This is one of the errors

`: undefined reference to Book::getData()'`

but it says it for the putData function as well

Comment: Are you compiling and linking in `classes.cpp`?

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages, especially if they're totally irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: oh. I dont think I am. Sorry im not used to compiling and forgot I have to compile several files now. Currently I was only running `"g++ .\main.cpp"` and thats when the errors pop up. How do i go about compiling classes.cpp @Kevin

Comment: On another note, please learn or refresh how to create a [mre]. The `main.cpp` file you show includes `task1.h` which is not shown in the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry it was meant to be `classes.h`, just thought classes.h would be more readable here but forgot to change it everywhere

Comment: `#include 'classes.h'` in the cpp file is also not good, you need double quotes.

Comment: youre right, not sure why its single quotes here but i used double quotes in my files @anastaciu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was just dumb and forgot that I need to compile both cpp files and not just `main.cpp`

Running `g++ main.cpp task1.cpp` caused no errors.